# How to create a reusable component with many possibilities based on the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, design-patterns

I'm making a blog website with a UI similar to https://atlas-demo.blogspot.com. A card component is used all over the main page, which has different layouts in different screen sizes. There is no specific pattern so I'm having difficulties creating a reusable component.

These are some of the possibilities for the card component:

Possibility #1

| Screen size | Layout |
| --- | --- |
| mobile | float |
| tablet | float |
| mobile | float |

Possibility #2

| Screen size | Layout |
| --- | --- |
| mobile | float |
| tablet | float |
| mobile | horizontal |

Possibility #3

| Screen size | Layout |
| --- | --- |
| mobile | horizontal |
| tablet | horizontal |
| mobile | float |

Possibility #4

| Screen size | Layout |
| --- | --- |
| mobile | vertical |
| tablet | vertical |
| mobile | vertical |

And by "float" and "horizontal" and "vertical" I mean

float:

[image]

horizontal:

[image]

vertical:

[image]

I can't find any pattern between these possibilities. My workaround is to pass a `layout` object to the component that defines the way it should look in different screen sizes. something like this:

```js
const layout = {
  mobile: "float",
  tablet: "horizontal",
  desktop: "horizontal"
}
```

And I add different classes based on the `layout` object:

```html
<div class={classnames(
        layout.mobile === "float" && "mobile:relative",
        layout.tablet === "float" && "tablet:relative",
        layout.desktop === "float" && "desktop:relative",

        layout.mobile === "horizontal" && "mobile:flex",
        layout.tablet === "horizontal" && "tablet:flex",
        layout.desktop === "horizontal" && "desktop:flex",

        layout.mobile === "vertical" && "mobile:flex mobile:flex-col",
        layout.tablet === "vertical" && "tablet:flex tablet:flex-col",
        layout.desktop === "vertical" && "desktop:flex desktop:flex-col",

     )}>
</div>
```

BTW this is JSX syntax with tailwindcss classes.

As you can see, it's very messy and it gets worst as the complexity grows:

1. What if I want the image to be in a square shape when the layout is not "float"?
2. What if I want to add something to the card, like an icon, but it should be in the corner for "horizontal" and "vertical" layouts and in the center for the "float" layout?

And so on.

So I like to hear your take on this. I don't want you to do my homework, I just need some ideas. Anything could be helpful. Maybe a design pattern that I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The areas are in my opinion still logically divided and each area can be given a unique css class.

eg top most slider can be `ticker` and the unique behavior is, the layout of each card doesn't change

the middle area with 5 cards can be `featured` and the unique behaviour is, except slider, all other cards change the layout at the different viewport, eg desktop and tablet = float and for mobile = horizontal

Similarly, the rest of the rules can be created based on the context.

It's hard to generalise and hence easy to hard code the configuration.

I am not a tailwind expert so can't give you an equivalent code. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Thank you for the response. You are absolutely right. I ended up creating different card components for different sections of the page.